# Number of Functions $\{1, 2, 3, . . . , n\}$ (and the number of permutations among them)

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, logic

For this problem, let $S_n$ be the set of numbers $\{1, 2, 3, . . . , n\}$

- How many functions are there that map $S_n$ to $S_n$?
- How many bijections are there that map $S_n$ to $S_n$?

We just got to functions, and I'm extremely lost when it comes to bijections, surjections, and injections.

Comment: I think you have a typo and that $\mathbb N$ was just supposed to be an $n$?

Comment: It goes from 1 to N. N isn't specified.

Comment: Sorry about that - it is "n."  My mistake!

Comment: How many different options are there to map $1$ to can you have $f(1) =7$.  Can you have $f(1)=4$.  Can you have $f(1)=1$?  And how many options are there that you can map $2$ to?  And $3$ to? Does it matter what $f(1)$ is to determine what $f(2)$ is?  Does it matter if $f$ is bijective?  Does it matter if $f$ isnt?

Comment: Hmmm.... the title $(1\mapsto n)$ doesn't really make any sense and I wonder why the OP wrote it.

Comment: @fleablood I changed it! Also, f(1) can map to N different numbers. Since there is N numbers, would number of functions be N*N, or N squared?

Comment: That's the total number of functions from $S_n$ to $S_n$.  If $A$ has $k$ elements and $B$ has $m$ elements then the number of functions $f:A\to B$ is $km$ as there are $m$ options for each of the $k$ elements.  ... Okay, but what if $f$ is bijective.  What restrictions does that have.  If $f(1) = 7$ what can and what can not $f(2)$ be equal to.

Comment: @fleablood Well in that case $f(2)$ can be anything but $7$, so the number of remaining possibilities for what it CAN be is $(n-1)$, then $(n-2)$, and so forth. I'm going to go on a limb here, and say that $n(n-1)(n-2)..$ yields $n!$ which is the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, I believe you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $f$ is a bijection, then the image of $f$ contains the same elements but "in a different order" (ex: $(1,2,3)\mapsto(2,3,1)$).

How many different ways are there to arrange $n$ things?

Comment: Right! That means $n!$. I assumed my universe of discourse has three elements to test this out, and uniquely it can only map to $6$ different functions, which is what $3!$ is equal to. Am I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It's a good idea to *once* in you lifetime list out all the functions from $\{1,2,3\}\to \{1,2,3\}$.  They are $A:(1\mapsto 1;2\mapsto 1;3\mapsto 1), B:(1\mapsto 1,2\mapsto 1, 3\mapsto 2), ...... etc Z: (1\mapsto 3;2\mapsto 3;3\mapsto 2) AA: (1\mapsto 3; 2\mapsto 3; 3\mapsto 3)$ and  look to see which are bijective...but... yes, your reasoning is correct and that is the correct answer.

Comment: @fleablood Yea I actually just did that, except I did that uniquely and I only got 6 unique functions for 3 variables, 2 unique functions for 2 variables. The only relationship I saw between these two is the $factorial$. Thank you for letting me see that!